# Change one cell's Style (to Bad) when another cell has been recently edited

Tags: excel, vba, styles, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a tool that's fool-proof to use.

Example; when someone edits cell H2 at all (even if they don't change it, so long as they start the editing phase), I want cell H3 to immediately change it's style to Bad (Red). Same for editing H30; changing H31, H58 changing H59, and H86 changing H87.

Would this be done via VBA or conditional formatting?

Comment: What do you consider "starting the editing phase"? Selecting the cell? Changing its value? Something else?

Comment: Changing the value.

Answer (score 1):

Just test for the change in the `Worksheet_Change` event.  Put something like this in the appropriate worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim addr As String
    addr = Target.Address
    Select Case addr
        Case "$H$2", "$H$30", "$H$58", "$H$86"
            Target.Offset(1).Style = "Bad"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H2, H30, H58, H$86")) Is Nothing Then Target.Offset(1).Style = "Bad"
End Sub
```

furthermore you may want to warn the users as soon as they enter any *forbidden* cell by applying an "Alert" style and remove it if the leave it without modification

in this case you could try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Const forbiddenRngAddr As String = "H2, H30, H58, H$86"
Dim oldRng As Range
Dim oldValue As Variant
Dim oldStyle As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(forbiddenRngAddr)) Is Nothing Then Target.Offset(1).style = "Bad"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not oldRng Is Nothing Then
        If Not Intersect(oldRng, Range(forbiddenRngAddr)) Is Nothing Then
            If oldValue = oldRng.Value Then oldRng.Offset(1).style = oldStyle
        End If
    End If
    With Target
        If Not Intersect(.Cells, Range(forbiddenRngAddr)) Is Nothing Then
            oldStyle = .Offset(1).style
            .Offset(1).style = "Alert"
        End If
        Set oldRng = .Cells
        oldValue = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally a more articulate code would be needed should you ever manage to handle any user amendment possibly after wandering about cells

Here I used comments to store improperly changed cells old value and style, to be retrieved and checked for subsequent user inputs

```
Option Explicit

Const forbiddenRngAddr As String = "H2, H30, H58, H$86"
Dim oldRng As Range
Dim oldValue As Variant
Dim oldStyle As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If Not Intersect(.Cells, Range(forbiddenRngAddr)) Is Nothing Then
            If .Comment Is Nothing Then
                .Offset(1).style = "Bad"
                With .AddComment
                    .Visible = False
                    .Text oldValue & "|" & Target.style
                End With
            Else
                If .Text = Split(.Comment.Text, "|")(0) Then
                    .Offset(1).style = Split(.Comment.Text, "|")(1)
                    .Comment.Delete
               Else
                    .Offset(1).style = "Bad"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not oldRng Is Nothing Then
        If Not Intersect(oldRng, Range(forbiddenRngAddr)) Is Nothing Then
            If oldValue = oldRng.Value Then oldRng.Offset(1).style = oldStyle
        End If
    End If
    With Target
        If Not Intersect(.Cells, Range(forbiddenRngAddr)) Is Nothing Then
            oldStyle = .Offset(1).style
            .Offset(1).style = "Alert"
        End If
        Set oldRng = .Cells
        oldValue = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Redlaw, did you get through it?